# How to get hold of reference to concrete type from reference to interface

Tags: go

I am trying to understand how methods, interfaces and concrete types work in Go work.

Like, [here](https://go.dev/tour/methods/9).

I have code as:

```
type I interface {MyMethod(....)}
type A struct{i I....} 
func (a *A) MyMethod(....) {
}
```

So A implements interface I.

In client code:

```
i := somefunction(....) // i is of type I
i.MyMethod(....)
```

How can I get hold of reference to A from i?

Comment: *"How can I get hold of reference to A from i?"* -- With a type assertion, or type switch, or with reflection.

Comment: *"So A implements interface I."* -- Not exactly, it's `*A` that implements the interface, `A` doesn't. Methods declared for `*A` will not be part of `A`'s method set. So a statement like `var i I = A{}` would fail to compile, while `var i I = &A{}` will compile.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. Go seems to be pretty unconventional to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A set of method signatures is stored in an interface type. Any implementation of the **defined methods in the interface** may be stored as its value.
- If a variable was defined with the interface type, *defined methods in the interface can be accessed* and other methods that are associated with the **type** of the implementation are *inaccessible*.

**Interface:**

```golang
type I interface {
    Value() string
}
```

**Implementation:**

```golang
type A string

func(a A) Value() string {
    return string(a)
}

func (a A) Type() string {
 return  reflect.TypeOf(a).Name()
}
```

**In client code:**

```golang
    // Define a variable with the type of I.
    var a I = A("a") 

    // Method Value() defined in the I interface can be
    // called.
    value := a.Value()

     // Method Type() can not be called, because it is not defined in the interface.
    typ := a.Type()
```

> **Note:** If methods were implemented with **pointer receivers**  as below. You need to assign pointer of the implementation to `i`.
>
> **Implementation:**
>
> ```golang
> type A string
> func(a *A) Value() string {
>   return string(a)
> }
> ```
>
> **In client code:**
>
> ```golang
>  a := A("a")
>  var i I = &a
> ```